# Chrome DevTools Network Throttling in Windows 7

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7

From the documents of [Chrome DevTool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#network-conditions) I have see this,

```
 One key aspect for the responsiveness of a site is its network performance. Fear not, the DevTools offers network throttling. Now you can test your site against different network conditions and optimize for them.

Network conditioning does bandwidth throttling and latency manipulation. The bandwidth is how much speed the client has to talk to the server while latency is the delay in connection. A few presets are available in the network dropdown, as well as the ability to go completely offline. All changes only affect this tab's traffic; your other tabs are unaffected.
```

But I am unable to find this option Chrome with Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Chrome DevTools page:

> Note: Some of our documentation **may be ahead of the stable version of Chrome**. If you are unable to locate a feature listed, we recommend trying Chrome Canary which contains the latest version of the DevTools.